# Get input from a command on Mutt

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, email, mutt

Mutt can be used to send email from command line, for that we do something like:

```
   mutt -s "Subject" -i file.txt -- someone@gmail.com < /dev/null
```

My file.txt can have the output of a command like

```
date > file.txt
```

How to I skip the part of generating `file.txt` and put the output of `date` directly on the mutt command?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass standard input as a body message to mutt:

```
date | mutt -s "Subject" -- toto@example.com
```

Comment: I want to pass a command output, instead. For example, pass the output of `date`. Can I pass the output of `date` instead of standard input?

Comment: @KcFnMi: the stdout of the date command is piped to stdin of mutt. That’s exactly what you want.